# Minimize cost given pickup and delivery with OR tools

Tags: python, or-tools

I have the following problem:

I have:

```
data["time_matrix"] # 2D list
data["pickups_deliveries"] # list of tuples, containing (start_node_index, end_node_indes)
data["vehicle_costs"] # list of 2D list of cost of route per vehicle
```

My goal is to complete all the deliveries on time (let's assume that it is possible) at minimized cost.

I know that I would need to create a `time_dimension`, since I need to keep track of cumulative time to make sure that I can deliver within given time windows.

However, I don't understand how to minimize cost?

When I set:

```
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
```

The `transit_callback_index` that I pass would be calculated based on `data["time_matrix"]`

How can I specify the `data["vehicle_costs"]`? And tell the solver to minimize it?

I looked at this issue: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1045, but it appears to me that in that case `cost_matrix` is used instead of `distance_matrix` (or `time_matrix`) not in conjunction with.

I mostly worked of this example: [Time Window Constraints](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw)

I am looking for some pointers and suggestions. Please let me know if I need to add more details or provide a concrete example.

Comment: seems to me a [travel salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: @prashantrana, this is a question about how to set it up using `or-tools` library

Comment: sorry my bad , i thought with those given data create a algorithm to handle the probkem

Comment: @prashantrana, no problem, I changed the title to clarify

Answer (score 1):

What I needed to do is:

set

```
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(..)
```

based on cost matrix, and then handle pickup and deliveries, with creating a time dimension.

Reading this bit of source code pushed me in the right direction.

```
  for (int vehicle = 0; vehicle < vehicles(); ++vehicle) {
    CostClass cost_class(vehicle_to_transit_cost_[vehicle]);

    // Insert the dimension data in a canonical way.
    for (const RoutingDimension* const dimension : dimensions_) {
      const int64 coeff = dimension->vehicle_span_cost_coefficients()[vehicle];
      if (coeff == 0) continue;
      cost_class.dimension_transit_evaluator_class_and_cost_coefficient
          .push_back({dimension->vehicle_to_class(vehicle), coeff, dimension});
    }
```

[source code for routing.cc](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.cc#L1214)